# how to use the userVariables in Testcafe using the CLI

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to use the new userVariables option, which is newly introduced in Testcafe's recent version.

I was wondering if the userVariables can be used through the CLI.

I understand that the variables could be added to the testcaferc.json as mentioned in the documentation:

https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#uservariables

I couldn't figure out a way to add or modify the variables and values through the command line.

Thanks in advance for any help/hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up custom user variables only in the configuration file. Please refer the following topic for more info: https://testcafe.io/403403/release-notes/framework/2021-9-8-testcafe-v1-16-0-released#support-for-custom-user-variables-in-the-configuration-file

Also, you might want to track the following issue in the TestCafe GitHub repository: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6621

Comment: Thanks @aleks-pro. appreciate the speedy response!